# CLIPUP.EXE : What will happen after accidental execution?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, license, license-key

I came across **clip.exe** which was a cli tool for capturing text from the command prompt into the windows clipboard.
I wanted to see if there was any other similar tool (eg to print the clipboard text into the command prompt) & then saw a similar-looking **clipup.exe**, which I ignorantly executed : no output.
I tried "clipup /?" and "help clipup" : no help available.
I did a web search and found that it is an unrelated tool : clipup == "Client License Platform Migration Tool".

Doubt : With no output, I am not sure if there is something going on internally to "migrate licenses". I have upgraded to windows 10 on my windows 8 laptop. Is it going to mess-up my existing license ? Can I reboot my laptop safely ? I hope it does not fail to reboot because of "license migration failed" or something like that.

In case that command did instruct windows to do something on reboot, Is there a way to cancel that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clipup.exe /?` doesn't seem to do anything, but it does show help when no parameters are used.

> clipup Usage:
>
> -?/-h   This help menu
>
> -p      Attempts to migrate data from the legacy Windows Phone database
>
> -o      Attempts to migrate data from Windows Genuine Authorization blob
>
> -altto  [path] Optional alternative Windows Genuine Authorization blob folder location
>
> -d      Generate a genuine ticket for the BIOS key
>
> -k      [5X5 product key] Windows 7/8/Blue product key
>
> -pfm    [package family name] Optional package family name to look for a migratable license
>
> -l      [path] Optional folder of legacy Windows Store licenses
>
> -v      Enables optional verbose logging [path]  Optional alternative output location for migrated data Done.

Nothing would happen when you run that file without the above mentioned parameters. I tested it.

Comment: Oh, thank you ! Strangely , on my windows 10 system ( upgraded from windows 8 ) there was no output initially. After a reboot , I too got the same help output ( It seems to be looking for -? or -h rather than /? or /h )